# Reducing a game of fractional dice rolls to a simple equation

Tags: probability, dice

Imagine a game where each player generates $r$ random integers in a fixed range $[1, m]$, and their score $s$ is the smallest number generated. Players are sorted by $s$, and the player with the smallest number wins.

Each player can have a different $r$ value (ie. how many "rolls of the dice" they get). Obviously, the higher your $r$ value, the higher your chances of winning.

Is it possible to achieve the same result (same winning probabilities) by only generating a single random number per player and applying a scaling factor (based on $r$)?

The motivation here is to be able to apply this formula to non-integer $r$ values.

Updated to clarify: the desired outcome is a sorted list of all players scores, not just a single winner.

Comment: Well, you can calculate the chances of each player winning and use those numbers.  Of course, that's a bit messy if the collections are large, but it works.  Of course, you can simulate the actual process to estimate those probabilities quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ties are rerolled among the tying dice: since each die is equally likely to be the smallest, this is equivalent to a lottery where each die is a ticket. Thus you can simply select the winning ticket by generating a single random number for the *entire contest*. This also makes the generalization from integers to reals trivial: each player's chance of winning is still their number of tickets divided by the total number of tickets in the game.

If you really do want to assign a single score to each player: The [Elo rating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) with a logistic curve also effectively models contests as lotteries, though usually in a 1v1 context. Here each player's ticket count is exponential in their Elo rating; equivalently, their Elo rating is logarithmic in their ticket count. Specifically, using the most common Elo scaling, a player's ticket count is

$$
r = 10^{\text{Elo rating} / 400} \approx e^{\text{Elo rating} / 173.7}
$$

In this case you can [have each player roll on a Gumbel distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution#Gumbel_reparametrization_tricks) with the same scaling and add it to their Elo rating; highest score wins. This is known as the "Gumbel-max trick".